# Functions - AzureWebJobsServiceBus set to key from rules created in same ARM template

Tags: azure-rm-template

I am writing an ARM template that deploys resources forming a part of an application.

- Service Bus, including namespace, queue and authorization rules.
- Azure Function triggered by the queue above.

The `AzureWebJobsServiceBus` app setting needs deploying for this Function trigger to work. Of course, the queue connection string contains the shared access key from the authorization rules created within the same ARM template.

I need to somehow build a connection string and refer to the key just made.

```
    "siteConfig": {
        "appSettings": [
            {
                "name": "AzureWebJobsServiceBus",
                "value": "[concat('Endpoint=sb://', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), '.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=sender-listener;SharedAccessKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/authorizationRules', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), '/http-push/sender-listener'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
            },
```

At the moment, the above is giving me this error.

> Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'mycompany-myapp-mycomponent-functionapp' at line '136' and column '9' is not valid: Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': function requires exactly one multi-segmented argument which must be resource type including resource provider namespace.

#### Update

The error was caused by my `dependsOn` though its the same syntax I'm using in my `value` above so it feels like progress. The correct syntax for my situation is:

```
"dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/authorizationRules', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), 'queue-name', 'auth-rule-name')]"
],
```

Still working on the other bit.

#### Update

Using this as the value for the app setting above causes a new error now.

```
"[concat('Endpoint=sb://', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), '.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=auth-rule-name;SharedAccessKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/authorizationRules', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), 'queue-name', 'auth-rule-name'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
```

> No registered resource provider found for location 'uksouth' and API version '2015-05-01-preview' for type 'namespaces/queues/authorizationrules'. The supported api-versions are '2014-09-01, 2015-08-01, 2017-04-01'. The supported locations are ''.

:(

#### Update

Switched the version of `listKeys` to `2017-04-01` and now have this very useful error!

> 'The language expression property 'key1' doesn't exist, available properties are 'primaryConnectionString, secondaryConnectionString, primaryKey, secondaryKey, keyName'.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay that took about 8 hours to sort. #productive

As per the error here:

> 'The language expression property 'key1' doesn't exist, available properties are 'primaryConnectionString, secondaryConnectionString, primaryKey, secondaryKey, keyName'.'

The connection string is available which sounds like it would negate the need for me to concat my own one, alas a Service Bus Queue trigger does not like the queue name on the end, so I must compose it manually like so.

```
"value": "[concat('Endpoint=sb://', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), '.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=auth-rule-name;SharedAccessKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/authorizationRules', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), 'queue-name', 'auth-rule-name'),'2017-04-01').primaryKey)]"
```